Spectrum of a strip operator using Tensor products
I'm trying to check whether my intuition is correct. I have square summable functions on the strip $\mathbb{Z}\times \{ 0, ..., \ell-1\}$, which I think can be identified with elements of $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{C}^{\ell}$. I have a Schrödinger like operator
$$ [H\psi](m_1,m_2)= \psi(m_1-1,m_2)+ \psi(m_1+1,m_2)+ \psi(m_1, m_2+1\mod \ell)+ \psi(m_1, m_2-1\mod \ell)+ V(m_2)\psi(m_1,m_2) $$
and I want to compute its spectrum. If I denote by $A$ the adjacency operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, I think I can write $H=A\otimes I_{\ell}+Id\otimes M$, where $I_\ell$ is the $\ell\times \ell$ identity matrix, $Id$ is the identity operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $M$ is some $\ell\times \ell$ self-adjoint matrix. Is it then true that $\text{spec}(H)=\text{spec}(A)+\text{spec}(M)$?
I think this follows for the tensor products of bounded operators, by this paper, that
$$ \text{spec}(T_1\otimes Id +Id\otimes T_2 )= \text{spec}(T_1\otimes Id)+\text{spec}(Id\otimes T_2)= \text{spec}(T_1)+\text{spec}(T_2). $$
I wanted to check if these arguments are a correct application of said paper.
